# visual studio C++ toggle comment ? comment while not whole line is selected?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, comments, toggle

2 questions actually :

1) shortcut to ***toggle comment*** on selected lines ? Available on all iDEs I used starting with notepad++

2)the `ctrl-k, ctrl-c` exhibits this behavior (quoted from someplace nicely worded):

> C#: Each line where some text is
>   selected is commented at the
>   line-start with double-slash. If
>   nothing is selected, the line where
>   the cursor is is commented.
>
> C++: If nothing is selected or
>   complete lines are selected, it
>   behaves as above. However, if parts of
>   a line are selected, and no comment is
>   selected as part of the selection (ex.
>   select something in the middle of a
>   code line), then the selection is
>   surrounded by /* and */.

since I code in C++ I find this behavior annoying - I want to be able to comment out lines partially selected - any workarounds ?

Comment: Well, the workaround is to select the whole line!

Comment: Can I vote down ? Even notepad++ has this behavior and it is really useful - you are in the midle of line with something selected - hit Alt-Q line commented out - I can't believe this is not possible in VS !

Comment: @user: You can't vote it down because it's not actually an answer lol. I didn't indend that to be a serious answer to the question, I more inteded it to be funny. Though I have to say this is a feature I'd never use -- It's almost as fast to press "Home" and then two /s as it would be to press the key combo (In fact it's one fewer keystroke!).

Comment: I know - was joking - well a matter of taste - also (more) useful when selecting multiple lines and do not caring to select exactly the whole of first and last - and how about the *toggle comment* part ?

Comment: Why is toggling comments so important? Is it that you do not have color coding turned on and so it is hard for you to tell whether a line is already commented or not? Just use `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C` for commenting and `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+U` for uncommenting. I'd much rather have the VS team implement things like code refactoring than fancy commenting shortcuts.

Comment: @Billy: Home and 2 /s is the same number of keystrokes as Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C if you hold the Ctrl key down while hitting K & C ;-)

Comment: @Praetorian - it is important, dear, when you comment out something, write and alternative below it and you want to *quickly* (without having to select the whole lines, just a quick mouse gesture) switch between the two - *for instance*. Gosh - I asked a question - either answer or not and please spare me the programming tips. And those "fancy" commenting shortcuts are *elementary* and present in all IDEs there are. I do agree that home//==Cntrl+K+C though.

Comment: Write a macro for the behavior you want, at least until VS2012 where MS took macros out!  Guess you'll have to use Notepad++ for that, too.

Comment: @MarkTolonen:lol I gave up a long time ago - when I come back I will be sure to bug you with how to write those macros :)

Answer (score 9):

*Each line where some text is selected is commented at the line-start with double-slash. If nothing is selected, the line where the cursor is is commented.*

**In case of multiline selection:**
My solution uncomments only if all the lines in the selection are commented. I found it more intuitive.

---

### Solution:

**Tools** -> **Macros** -> **Macros IDE...**

In **Macro Explorer** right click on *Macros* and click **New Macro Project...**

Name your macro for e.g. **MyMacroProject** and click **Add**.

Right click on **Module1** in your new macro project in *Macro Explorer*
and click **Edit**.

Paste this into the macro editor window:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit Off
Imports EnvDTE
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Module Module1
    Sub ToggleCommentLine()
        Dim sel As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection

        Dim firstLine As Integer = sel.TopPoint.Line
        Dim lastLine As Integer = sel.BottomPoint.Line

        sel.GotoLine(firstLine, True)
        sel.LineDown(True, lastLine - firstLine)
        sel.EndOfLine(True)

        'we un-comment only if there is no commented line
        Dim allLinesCommented As Boolean = True

        Dim lineIndex As Integer = firstLine
        While allLinesCommented And (lineIndex <= lastLine)
            sel.GotoLine(lineIndex, True)
            allLinesCommented = Regex.IsMatch(sel.Text, "^\s*//.*$")
            lineIndex += 1
        End While

        'iterate over the lines
        For lineIndex = firstLine To lastLine
            sel.GotoLine(lineIndex, True)
            Dim line As String = sel.Text
            Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(line, "^(\s*)(//)(.*)$")
            If allLinesCommented Then
                sel.Text = m.Groups(1).Value & m.Groups(3).Value
            ElseIf Not m.Success Then
                sel.StartOfLine(vsStartOfLineOptions.vsStartOfLineOptionsFirstColumn)
                sel.Text = "//"
            End If
        Next

        'select all the affected lines
        sel.GotoLine(firstLine, True)
        sel.LineDown(True, lastLine - firstLine)
        sel.EndOfLine(True)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Save this file and close the macro editor window.

Bind your macro to a key:

**Tools** -> **Options...** -> **Environment** -> **Keyboard**

Type this into *Show commands containing:* 
`ToggleCommentLine`

Select Macros.MyMacroProject.Module1.ToggleCommentLine.

Set a key at *Press shortcut keys:* .
, then click **Assign**, then click **OK**.

Enjoy.

Comment: Very cool, thank you! I guess the bounty is for you, I'll just wait a few more days to see if anyone else wants to answer.

Comment: Actually I have one remark: you seem to use a C-specific regex to do the work. Wouldn't it be better to use Visual Studio's commenting and uncommenting functions which are far more general and more robust?

Comment: Can you mention any use case when this solution is not general or robust enough ? You would like it to exclude lines from comment when is executed inside a multi line comment (`/* ... */`) ?

Comment: any non-C language, for instance. Haskell, HTML, you name it!

Comment: I know Haskell but I thought we are talking about C++ now :/

Comment: @static_rtti: you are right - this solution needs to be made more generic - I would accept it if made more generic and tested by you (I do not have VS installed). ch0kee : "I thought we are talking about C++ now" -->general, _reusable_ code is always better than one shot hack - better rich and healthy than poor and sick as the saying goes. Moreover the question does not talk about toggling comments in C++ - although I was coding in C++ at the time - and everywhere this feature is offered is _offered_ (for all supported languages) ;)

Comment: I did mention C++ :) The bounty is for you. However, If you or someone else wants to make it more generic, I think it would be a very useful thing.

Comment: See Tools->Option->Encironment->Keyboard

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is intentional. If the user needed a tiny temporary change to a single line that did not require the entire line to be re-written, using the Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C shortcut pair allows him/her to comment out just the change and not the entire line.

Edit:

As for question one, it's the same shortcut pair: Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C to toggle any comments on, Ctrl+K, Ctrl+U to toggle any comments off.

Edit 2:

If you are still unsatisfied, get Visual Assist X from whole tomato software: http://www.wholetomato.com/
It adds an additional comment shortcut mapping to the '/' and '*' keys when text is highlighted.

Comment: I do agree it can be useful - it should have another shortcut though -- any ideas about q1 ?

Comment: Thanks - but toggle comment means to select some lines which are commented and some which are not and *toggle their comment status simultaneously*

Answer (score 0):

If you like to change the key shortcut of toggle comments to `ctrl`+`/` key. You can Hot command for visual studio and install it. Once you restart Visual Studio, it works!

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.HotCommandsforVisualStudio

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2019 you can get almost exactly the functionality you are looking for by triple-clicking the first line and then dragging to the bottom line. This will select full lines.

Then use Ctrl-K Ctrl-C as usual. It will insert `//` and not `/**/`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension that has a more "natural" toggle comment experience. It does not comment blank lines, but it does uncomment a selected block of text with blank lines therein.

Be warned that it's default key binding, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> conficts with a command in VS 2019, so it won't be set upon install, but the documentation shows you how to change it.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=munyabe.ToggleComment

Answer (score -2):

Toggle IS NOT the same as Toggle On and Toggle Off.

If I Toggle a group of lines - some of which are commented out, and others are not,
then a TOGGLE would comment out the lines that were previously not commented out and Un-Coment out the the line that were previously commented out - with a SINGLE keystroke.

Comment: Yes - that is what the question is about - you should add this as a comment to the other answer not as an answer