# Visual Studio C++ Multiline comments: have to select full line (including indention of first line) to use C++-comment

Tags: visual-studio, comments, visual-studio-2022

Let's say I have the following code:

```
if(true)
{
    int a=1;
    long b=1;
    long long c=1;
}
```

Now I select from `i` of `int a=1;` to `;` of `long long c=1;`, and press CTRL+K+C. I expect to see '//' (C++-comment) added to each line of code, but instead I got /**/ (C-comment).

To get C++-comment, I need to include the indention in front of `int a=1;` into my selection, which is annoying, since most selection shortcuts won't behave this way(shift+home+end or tripple-click selection)

Visual Studio Version: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 17.5.1

Have checked [visual studio C++ toggle comment ? comment while not whole line is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350744/visual-studio-c-toggle-comment-comment-while-not-whole-line-is-selected) and [Visual Studio C++ Multiline comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872680/visual-studio-c-multiline-comments?noredirect=1&lq=1). The macro solution of the first link seems nice, but I failed to find macro-related option in VS2022. Moreover, I don't think the behaviour mentioned above is a intended 'feature'