# How to comment multiple lines in visual studio using "//" instead of "/*"

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

When using the comment shortcut `Ctrl+K+C` it comments like this:

```cs
/*totaly();
legit.code()*/
```

This is very inconvenience when you what to uncomment just part of the code. Is there a way to comment multiple lines at the same time like this?

```cs
//totaly();
//legit.code()
```

I am using normal Visual Studio, not VS Code.

Comment: Hi, normally I use VS with the keboard-shorcuts of `vscode` and to do that I press `Ctrl+/`. With the default Visual Studio keyboard-shorcuts when I press `Ctrl+K+C` it comments all with the `//`. What version Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Comments will use `//` if the selection is comprised of full lines. If you want partially selected lines to be fully commented, see [visual studio C++ toggle comment ? comment while not whole line is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350744/visual-studio-c-toggle-comment-comment-while-not-whole-line-is-selected).

Comment: @JorgeMorgado Visual studio 2019 community

Comment: @BrunoJambeiro that's the same VS I use normally. Go to Tools > Options > Keyboard and you will find all you need

Comment: can't believe threr's no solution for this simple basic feature...